# Laravel Queue not working

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I'm trying to send out push notifications to an iOS app with a queue in Laravel. I wrote the code below:

```
$message = PushNotification::Message($notification,array(
            'custom' => array($custom_message),
            'category' => 'ACTIONABLE'
));

Queue::push(function($job) use ($id)
{
    $push = PushNotification::app($appname)
            ->to($device)
            ->send($message);
});
```

However, this isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I am having the same issue with queues.

Comment: @DanWhite still haven't, but my best guess is that the library doesn't support it yet.